# Powershell buffer & scroll distance

Tags: powershell, console, buffer

Is there a mechanism to set the console buffer height very high, so that a large amount of data can be echoed to the console for review, but somehow limit the scroll distance to what has actually been echoed, rather than the overall buffer size? It's a bit ridiculous when the output could be anywhere from tens to many hundreds of lines to set the buffer to 500 or a thousand and then have this massive amount of empty scroll area when the output is actually much smaller. Seems to me that the scroll should only ever be what is actually there, not the full buffer, and this is really an issue of how the console is implemented. And likely the real answer is I should roll my own Forms based "console". But still hoping I am just missing a setting for the console that can be managed by script.

Comment: Have you considered redirecting output to a file with, say, `Tee-Object` instead?

Comment: I already output to a file for later reference, but the process I am automating is potentially a number of hours of software install and management tasks (Autodesk software takes FOREVER to install) and I want a real time on screen log so people can see where in the process a machine is on a moments notice, review errors, etc. Then they also have the file log for review later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, not exactly.   The screen buffer gets allocated at the time you resize it.  Obviously you could save the results to the file, then resize the buffer after you know how long it is, and send the file contents to output as a final step.

Or you might get the effect you want with something like this:

```
$bufferSize = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(120,5000)
Clear-Host
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $bufferSize
# Generate output
1..111  # DUMMY OUTPUT
# Resize screen buffer
$bufferSize.Height = $host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition.y + 2
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $bufferSize
```

But that isn't realtime...  Perhaps by spawning a job and querying it with `Receive-Job` you could manage to resize the buffer on the fly.

This code might be of interest to you, does a lot of manipulation of console buffer contents:  http://poshcode.org/730